# Desktop app + Microsoft Authentication Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, desktop-application, ms-adal-angular

I have limited knowledge for the desktop app Development, and I have developed an application in the Hybrid platform, and I am facing this error message during Microsoft Authentication (Azure ad) from the desktop app.
**Only continue if you downloaded the app from a store or website that you trust.**

if any configuration needs to change from the Azure app or I am missing something which then, please help me.

[image]

I have checked the log in Azure,
**AADSTS50199   CmsiInterrupt** -
For security reasons, user confirmation is required for this request. Because this is an "interaction_required" error, the client should do interactive auth. This occurs because a system webview has been used to request a token for a native application - the user must be prompted to ask if this was actually the app they meant to sign into. To avoid this prompt, the redirect URI should be part of the following safe list:
http://

https://

msauth://(iOS only)

msauthv2://(iOS only)

chrome-extension:// (desktop Chrome browser only)

Comment: Looks it is not an error, why not click `Continue`?

Comment: Hi @JoyWang, thanks for your comment, I have tried it, but nothing happening when I click on Continue and Cancel both.

Comment: Which doc did you refer to configure the AAD auth?

Comment: this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Comment: @Spanchal did you resolve this issue for me also getting the same thing. What is the solution for this? Could please tell me if resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

To configure the desktop application with Azure AD auth,  and you want to sign in users to your application, you could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-overview).

Make sure you configured the App registration as the public client, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-app-registration). Then use the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-app-configuration?tabs=dotnet).