# Redirect Uri is not working in react native for msal

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory

I have a react-native app in which I am trying to move to msal from adal using the react-native-app-auth library in which finally after authentication I am getting this window that "Only continue if you downloaded the app from a store or website you trust", as clicking any button does not work, I found one issue related ([Desktop app + Microsoft Authentication Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577935/desktop-app-microsoft-authentication-error)) but there is also no solution provided there too and I have tried with the HTTP:// URLs too.
So, did any one of you faced the same issue, so please help in the resolution. [The final window I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD36A.jpg)

Comment: Did you add '`Redirect URIs`' under '`Mobile and desktop applications`'?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Azu.png

Comment: Yes, it is added and I also added some https: URIs, but still I am getting that window.

Answer (score 0):

According to your follow-up comment I notice that you are facing redirect URL issue. In Redirect URI, select Web and type /.auth/login/aad/callback.

For example:https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback.

Follow these steps and ensure all steps are followed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-your-app-service-app

Enable Azure active directory in you App Service app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-enable-azure-active-directory-in-your-app-service-app